# When trying to build I got this error - Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone help me with this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

Those are my pubspec.yaml dependencies (I have updated them all to the latest versions):

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  in_app_purchase: ^0.3.4+5
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  intl: ^0.16.0
  http: ^0.12.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  sentry: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"
```

Full stack of the error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Invalid depfile: /home/dimitar/Dropbox/flutter/nufc/.dart_tool/flutter_build/6fca2b889a0849e99a4ed0a0ec9503c5/kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: /home/dimitar/Dropbox/flutter/nufc/.dart_tool/flutter_build/6fca2b889a0849e99a4ed0a0ec9503c5/kernel_snapshot.d
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sentry-3.0.1/lib/src/browser.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' hide Event, Client;
       ^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:34:18: Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
  final _xhrs = <HttpRequest>{};
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sentry-3.0.1/lib/src/browser.dart:51:19: Error: Getter not found: 'window'.
    origin ??= '${window.location.origin}/';
                  ^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:34: Error: 'Blob' isn't a type.
      var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);
                                 ^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:46:15: Error: The method 'HttpRequest' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'HttpRequest'.
    var xhr = HttpRequest();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:42: Error: The method 'Blob' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Blob'.
      var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);
                                         ^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:59:20: Error: The method 'FileReader' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FileReader'.
      var reader = FileReader();
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:853:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:574:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:43:22)
#5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:182:27)
#6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:9:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/dimitar/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/dimitar/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My flutter doctor:

```
/home/dimitar/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Linux, locale bg_BG.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at /home/dimitar/flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (преди 6 дена), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/dimitar/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 30.0.0
    • Java binary at: /usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /usr/local/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64 • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

So far I have tried:

- Update flutter to the latest version
- Update dependencies to the latest versions
- Delete cache folder inside flutter/bin and then run `flutter doctor`
- Deleted pubspec.lock file and then run `flutter pub get`
- Running `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please before trying the method below first try to do all the solutions posted under "So far I have tried" and if any of the don't work I have manage to fix this issue by simple comment the dependencies that give errors in my case **http** and **sentry** and then run `flutter pub get` and then uncomment the dependencies and then run `flutter pub get` again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

change to http: in your pubspec and delete pubspec.lock file and try again

Comment: it is already http and I have already tried that, but I found an answer, thanks

Comment: i mean http:  without a version anyways u found it...